# Tesseract OCR C#: Training the network for unknown font

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

So I am using Tesseract with C# to read english text and it works like a charm. I use pre-trained data from the tesseract repo:https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata

So far, so good. However, I fail to understand how to solve the following situation: I have an image with a maximum of three numbers on it:[image]

I also followed this tutorial in order to train my own data but I failed to understand what exactly I am doing mid-way:https://pretius.com/how-to-prepare-training-files-for-tesseract-ocr-and-improve-characters-recognition/

In this tutorial, they used some existing font and train their network accordingly. However, I do not know what this font is. I tried to figure it out myself but was overwhelmed by the huge amount of information about tesseract and actually do not have any idea where to start.

I was wondering if the following would be possible: I have lots of pictures looking like that(in fact, every possible character with every possible color, only difference is that the background is different):
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
etc...

And with those pictures, I want to train the network, without using any existing font files.

My algorithm right now does not use tesseract, it just screenshots the position of the numbers and I compare pixel-wise. I do not like this appoach though, as the accuracy is something like 60%.

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Do you need to train?  Link says you only need to train if you do not get good results.

Comment: Yes I do, I let it run a few times and it always gives an empty string as a result

Comment: You can create the png file by pasting the images into Paint and save as png.  I would use Power Point and paste number images into power point and arrange the number images so they are uniformed (easy to do than in paint). then copy/paste the Power Point results into Paint and save as png.

Comment: Okay, but in what way would that help me? I already have all numbers as pngs

Comment: You need to train on your images. Putting in one file you can then train following the instructions in the link.